# How do you force a refresh of web app documents in iPhone Safari?

Tags: iphone, caching, web-applications

I can't seem to get, especially css-files, to refresh in my iPhone web-app (added to home screen) as I update the files on the server.

I have tried...

***Clear history (in settings)**

*Clear cache (in settings)

*Force closing and restarting the app

*Restarting the iPhone

It just randomly refreshes the files after a few tries.. very annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep I have the same issue. the only thing I have found that works is renaming the files (and changing the links to those files), which  is s brute force solution to say the least, leaving aside that in my case, since a lot of the files are added via php and the template frame work, a massive, massive pain in the ass.

Apparently using a manifest will help, but I have read that this actually doesn't solve the issue permanently as those files get cached aswell after the first time.

Apple really need to sort this as it makes developing, deploying and updating web apps un-necessarily laborious, since you should be able to update a css file without having to rename it in order for it to get refreshed. I appreciate the need for caching, but surely removing the web app entirely should remove the cache aswell- It seems a totally inefficient use of phone space to store a bunch of css files that no app is using.

Will post a better answer of I find one...

**UPDATE** This seems to be fixed in the latest version of iOS5 :)

Answer (score 0):

David O'Sullivan,

With the latest iOS 5.1.1 update, I still have this problem...
I'm not planning to rename the css file with every adjustment I make.

There are so many webapp developers nowadays, how can they work with such a hassle?
They must have fixed it somehow?

EDIT: After I changed my css filename 2 times, it now seems to be resolved. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like PHP to create these pages the ugly but working workaround could be adding random text after the CSS links. This would make the browser see this file as a different file, since the URL is different

```
<link href="styles.css?234234234234" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

with something like

```
echo "<link href='styles.css?'".time()." rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the app, then re-add it to home screen via Safari.
It's a bit annoying—I know, but if you keep Safari handy it can be done in a few seconds.